# Marble Draw Game

Tags: probability

How does one setup expected value problems like the one below? I need to be able to solve these without a calculator.

Below is a specific example of a question I have.

100 marbles each with numbers 1-100 marked on them. Draw them at random. You get the dollar amount of marble drawn. If not satisfied then you must pay $1 to roll again. What is the fair value of this game (up to how much would you pay to play this game)?

I would greatly appreciate if an answer could be provided that shows how to approach questions like this with slight variations. Eg. Pay 1/x (where x is amount drawn. So if you draw 100 pay 1 cent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems obvious that your strategy has to be to roll until you roll at least some $n$ and quit there.  You then have a payoff that is expected to be $50+\frac n2$ because it is equally distributed between $n$ and $100$ and an expected number of rolls of $\frac {100}{101-n}$.  So the value of the game is $50+\frac n2 -\frac {100}{101-n}$.  The derivative of this is $\frac 12-\frac {100}{(101-n)^2}$  Setting this to zero, we find $n=101-\sqrt {200}\approx 86.86$.  We try $86,87$ and find the greater value at $87$ with a value of $86\frac 5{14}$.  As the price of a roll goes down, $n$ will increase because it won't cost so much to keep trying.

Added:  if the price of a roll after the first is 1 divided by the previous roll, we need to assess the expected cost of a roll.  It is $\frac 1{n-1}(1+\frac 12 + \frac 13 +\dots \frac 1{n-1})=\frac 1{n-1}H_{n-1}\approx \frac {\log n+\gamma}{n-1}$ where $H_{n-1}$ is the $n-1^{\text{st}}$ [harmonic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), about $0.5772156649$.  Then we want to maximize $50+\frac n2-\left(\frac {100}{(101-n)}-1\right)\frac{(\log n + \gamma)}{(n-1)}$.  The $-1$ comes about because I don't pay for the first roll.  This doesn't look easy to do algebraically, so I fed it to [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize%2050%2bn/2-%28100/%28101-n%29-1%29%28log%28n%29%2b0.577%29/%28n-1%29) and found the maximum at $n=98$ with value $97.2793$  That seems surprisingly high for $n$, but rolls come really cheaply in this game.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I adapt your solution to account for paying 1/N rather than $1 per roll? When I attempt to solve I get a quartic root- is there a simple way to solve as presented above?

Comment: Is your $N$ a constant or some value that depends on the roll?  If a constant, you multiply the last term by $\frac 1N$, which winds up under the $200$ in the square root sign, but it is just a constant.  I don't see where the quartic comes from.

Comment: 1/n depends on the roll. One roll you could pay 1/2 and another 1/50 (rolling 2 then 50). I should have labeled the variable something else. --> 1/P

Comment: So the first roll I pay the value of the game, but for each successive roll I pay 1 divided by the previous roll?  That does make it harder.

Answer (score 0):

You begin by computing the expectation of the winnings at each step:

$$E[X_i] = \sum_{k=1}^{100} k\cdot P(X_i=k).$$

Assuming you sample without replacement, $P(X_i = k)$ is simply one divided by the number of remaining balls. So at the first turn, $i=1$, $P(X_i = k) = \frac{1}{100}$; at step 2, it's $\frac{1}{99}$, and so on.

You have an initial payment, $Y$, which increases by 1 for each subsequent turn. Subtract this off of the expected winnings at each step.

If we sample without replacement, the game has a terminal condition. Therefore, how to set $Y$ to determine fairness depends on your definition of fairness. One way is the set it so that your total expected winnings after 100 drawings is equal to zero.

Comment: To clarify, I am asking what is the optimal stopping point for this game. At which number should one stop playing?

Comment: @QRIUS2KNW Oh. Well, your post states "What is the fair value of this game." But this is equivalent to stopping time, since total cost is just initial cost + 1 dollar times stopping time.